# how to get mysql query result in jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
// assuming your SQL Server's username is "username" // and password is "password"

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "Select count(role) as totalEmployee from login where role = 'employee'";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

I fired this query in mysql and I got the answer is 2.
So how can I get and display the result of this query in jsp page?

Comment: This is really bad if you are doing this in a jsp. Ever heard of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)? Also... a huge no-no is that you've not closed the connection so you have a leak. Your aplication will soon run out of db connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate result-set and get result in variable like :

```
  <%
    int totalEmployee = 0;
    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
         totalEmployee = rs.getInt("totalEmployee");
    }
%>
```

Comment: In JSP anywhere you can display that result as
Total Employees : <%=totalEmployee %>

Comment: As good programming practice you should add this query part in servlet and then set that result-set as request attribute and get the same in jsp.
After that you can use that in jsp.

Comment: Yes , I exactly did the same what you suggest to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also display result-set and get result in variable like :

```
  <%

    while( rs.next()) {
         String= rs.getstring(1);
    }
%>
```